# Should Exception from my Business logic ever propagate to my controller.

Tags: domain-driven-design, software-design, solid-principles

What's the best practice for handling exceptions initiated from your business logic. e.g. When use case data validation fails.

Should this exception propagate to your controller, or you handle it in the business logic and return a more structured error message to the controller.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of error cases you're talking about? Which layer do you man by "business logic"? Use case input data validation (as in: required data, max length, etc.) is not something you typically do in the application layer, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

There are different takes on this so I don't think that you are going to get a "best practice" :)

I am more inclined to allow exceptions in my domain to propagate all the way to the integration layer which is the controller in a rest-api scenario.  An exception in the domain really is an "exception" so passing back some structured piece of data probably isn't really necessary.  You *may* opt to add some code to your exception using some convention or some such.  However, if you are handling specific exceptions you may have a specific class represent that exception in which case you know exactly what happened.  The only problem with that is when this individual exception list start becoming unwieldy.

I tend to use a generic `BusinessException`.  For cases where you are going to want to localize the message, for instance, you would need to perhaps have the message contain some codified data:

For instance:

```
throw new BusinessException("[BC-Account-Invalid-E-Mail]: Invalid e-mail address specified.");
```

But these are going to be implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different practices, that apply in different contexts.

In the case of `data validation`, your code paths won't normally reach the business logic.

For instance, suppose I have a web endpoint that is supposed to accept `bids`, where each bid message should describe a target item, and a bid price, and a bidder and so on.  If the message is wrong -- somebody put a date where the bid price is supposed to be, or the target item id  has the wrong format, or whatever -- then the usual practice is to short circuit the business logic out of the loop entirely, much as you would if you received an HTTP request message with an unrecognized method.

```
FormData -> BidMessage | ParseError
```

Is the basic idea.

```
Either<BidMessage, ParseError> parse(FormData formData)
BidMessage parse(FormData formData) throws ParseError
void parse(FormData formData, BidMessageHandler onBid, ParseErrorHandler onError)
```

The concept works in several different implementation styles.

> But wouldn't this affect being able to test the business logic independently?

I don't think so?  The test rig can create messages just as easily as the application can.

One way of framing the question is to consider the parallel case from the repository.  We are readying bytes out of our persistence appliance, and somehow those bytes need to be understood by the domain model -- what happens if *that* data validation fails?

Part of the point of having a repository abstracting away storage concerns is that it allows the business logic to be completely free of them.  We want the same kind of isolation from the implementation concerns of the input.

Comment: Thanks, @voiceOfUnreason for the explanation. But wouldn't this affect being able to test the business logic independently? If my test case has a bad bid message (Maybe a particular required field is not provided), that might result in my business logic throwing some kinda exception.